# What happens in IIS/C# when a request is aborted

Tags: c#, ajax, iis, xmlhttprequest

So I'm thinking about a functionality where the user pastes a link and the server-side code crawls the provided link and responds with the contents of that link (such as page title, description, thumbnail, etc).

The user can meanwhile change the link, and in doing that, the ajax-request should be aborted client-side.

I'm wondering what exactly happens in the IIS server and specifically to my C# code.

- Is the response thread terminated?
- Does the Response object now return null, or Response.Write throw exceptions?
- Is an exception thrown in the response thread just whereaver it is? (that one doesn't even make sense, but whatever)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the server code checks the state of `Response.IsClientConnected`, it can stop the work and produce an empty response when the client aborts the request, otherwise it will just complete the request as usual.

The request handling will not be aborted automatically just because there is noone waiting for it any more. The server code has to actively check the state of the request.

Answer (score 2):

Your web server doesn't know that the client cancelled the request.  The request will still be fulfilled and a response will be sent back.  The client-side script that you write will need to be able to handle what the current state of your page should be.

If you are certain that you don't care about the response, I would recommend aborting the request client-side:

```
xhr.abort()
```

Comment: So my web server's code is executed to completion? what would be the point in aborting a request, then?

Comment: So there are usually two steps (simplified) to an Ajax request.  1. Kick off the request.  2. Do something with the response (a success or failure callback).  If you abort the request, then your callback methods won't have to handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you close the connection client side before the response is written an error stating as much is thrown. You could just choose not to handle the response when it comes back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Once a request is posted to server the IIS will start executing the server side code. Now the server can decide upon whether the code needs to be executed or not.

In the entire page cycle you can check Request.IsClientConnected  as mentioned by Guffa and terminate the execution.

But yes it totally depends on the scenario you have.

Hope it helps.